# Store image in arrylist in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display image from services.js file and the image is from src under the assets folder and I want to store the image in services.js from assets but when I give a file path it doesn't display image. Here is my code: how to give file path name in js which is in different folder.
My image relative path is src\assets\Mover.jpg.
and my service.js relative path is src\Services.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Services.css";

export default class Services extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const Services = [
      {
        id: 0,
        Mover_src: "./assets/Mover.jpg",
        title: "Plumbing Services",
        overview: "hello this is plumbing service"
      },
     {id:1,
      Mover_src: "./assets/plumb.jpg",
      title:"Moving Services", 
      overview:"hello this is plumbing service"}

    ];

    var serviceRows = [];
    Services.forEach(service => {
      console.log(service.title);
      const serviceRow = (
        <table key={service.id}>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <img alt="Mover" width="300" src={service.Mover_src} />
              </td>
              <td>{service.title}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
      serviceRows.push(serviceRow);
    });
  this.state = { rows: serviceRows };
 }
 render(){
   return(
     <div className="main">
      {this.state.rows}
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Create React App or something else that does the configuration for you? If so, you can probably just do `import Mover from './assets/Mover.jpg'` and use that as the src.

Comment: yes, I'm using create react app.i did import Mover from './assets/Mover.jpg' but it says 'Mover' is defined but never used. I have Mover.jpg image inside the assets folder.

Comment: yes, use `Mover` as the src. See [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) from the CRA documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```js
const Services = [
      {
        id: 0,
        Mover_src: "./assets/Mover.jpg",
        title: "Plumbing Services",
        overview: "hello this is plumbing service"
      },
     {id:1,
      Mover_src: "./assets/plumb.jpg",
      title:"Moving Services", 
      overview:"hello this is plumbing service"}

    ];
```

to:

```js
const Services = [
      {
        id: 0,
        Mover_src: require("./assets/Mover.jpg"),
        title: "Plumbing Services",
        overview: "hello this is plumbing service"
      },
     {id:1,
      Mover_src: require("./assets/plumb.jpg"),
      title:"Moving Services", 
      overview:"hello this is plumbing service"}

    ];
```

so webpack could import them correctly.

Comment: it says Error: Cannot find module '.assets/Mover.jpg'

Comment: then the file is not located there, put the correct relative path in there and it works!

Comment: but when I do  in css :-  url("./assets/Mover.jpg"); it displays the image. and in services.js file when i try to compile with warning Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression and errors shows Error: Cannot find module './assets/Mover.jpg'

Comment: so `assets` directory is under `public` directory?

Comment: no it is under the src directory my relative path is src\assets\Mover.jpg

Comment: I need extra information about your file tree, could you edit you question and add a simple tree?

Comment: I Have edited the question and mentioned the relative path of image and file I want to use that image.